# error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io/

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, web3js

We have not created Expo project

We have created react-native project using init command

Using the below react-native version:
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0",

After run in iOS getting below error
error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io/

Comment: https://mainnet.infura.io/ is throwing a 404 page not found for me

Comment: You need to provide code to get help. Did you create an API key with Infura? Do any of the test networks work for you? Is this only a problem in iOS or does it fail in Android as well?